# Real Time Local File Sync

Tags: rsync, synchronization, real-time

How can I set up an *instant* file sync for two local directories?  The catch is I need it in real time (15, 10 or even 5 seconds is too slow), and I don't want the target root directory created.

For example, something similar to...

```
cp -fr sourcea/* /some/destdir
cp -fr sourceb/* /some/destdir
cp -fr sourcec/* /some/destdir
```

Catching deletions would be nice too, though it's not a deal breaker.

I do not want the "sourcex" created within destdir. (hence the *).  I've tried using rsync, which apparently wasn't close or even close to real-time, as well as several generic sync systems.  However, most will want a 1 to 1 sync, rather than contents only.

Any suggestions?  I've been fighting this for a while now, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A filesystem overlay would probably work better for this. Using something like [aufs](http://aufs.sourceforge.net/) you can create a 'virtual' directory out of several combined directories. You can configure whether writes should propagate back to the original directories, or use a copy-on-write method to leave the originals alone, or disallow writes altogether.

However to answer your original question, you can use something like [lsyncd](http://code.google.com/p/lsyncd/) to trigger an rsync as soon as a file is modified. lsyncd uses rsync, which is capable of syncing directory contents without keeping the directory name. Generally the way to do this is to sync `sourcea/.` to `/some/destdir/`. The important part is the dot at the end of the source path. This is a general trick that can be used for things other than rsync, like cp.